# infinite ring with non-zero finite characteristic

Tags: positive-characteristic

For every natural number *n*, i have to give a finite and a infinite ring with characteristic *n*.

For the finite case is it simple: for all *n* $\in\mathbb{N}$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a finite ring with characteristic *n*. 
But in the infinite case i can't think of a ring...

The only infinite ring with a finite characteristic that is not 0, is the ring of all subsets of a infinite set X. With the operations of symmetric difference and intersection. Here is the characteristic equal to 2.

Comment: The characteristic is always $0$ or a prime number. So there's *no way* you will have something of characteristic $4$...

Comment: @user10000100_u: Characteristic of a ring $A$ is the generator of the kernel of the natural map $\mathbb Z \to A, 1 \mapsto 1.$

Comment: Let me put it differently : the notion of characteristic is not *pertinent* for all rings. Because honestly, we really don't want to say that $\mathbf{Q}$, as well as $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}\times\ldots$, are of characteristic $0$, do we ?... You see what I mean ?...

Comment: @user10000100_u: Yes! I think I understood what you mean. But that's how it's defined for rings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider the ring $\Bbb Z_n[x]$ of polynomials in one variable $x$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z_n$, where $n$ is prime.  It is an infinite ring since $x^m \in \Bbb Z_n[x]$ for all positive integers $m$, and $x^{m_1} \ne x^{m_2}$ for $m_1 \ne m_2$.  But the charactetistic of $\Bbb Z_n[z]$ is clearly $n$.

Comment: The assumption that $n$ be prime is unnecessary for the above result.

Comment: Is $x^m$ a short hand notation for the whole polynomial with its degree $m$ ?

Comment: @SubhamKarmakar: yes

Answer (score 4):

$A_n:= \prod \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ (infinite product, fixed $n$). This is an infinite ring with characteristic $n.$

Comment: oke thnx! is the infinite product $\prod \mathbb{Z}_n$ also an infinte ring with characteristic n?

Comment: @RobbeMotmans: Do you mean the product is over $n$? In this case it will be of characteristic zero, since there is no $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $m\cdot 1=0.$

Comment: i meant an infinite cartesian product, so that you have elements of the form (a,b,c,d,...) with a,b,c,d $\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. So you will have a set with an infinite number of elements. Is the characteristic still n in this case?

Comment: Yes! That's the example I gave. (By $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ I mean "integer modulo $n$" which is $\mathbb Z_n$ in your notations)

Comment: In some books (e.g. I. N. Herstein) the characteristic is defined only for Integral Domains, so for that $A_n$ as you defined fails to be an example (even if $n$ is prime)