# Is there a ring R with infinite elements with $\mathrm{char}(R)$ not $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

True or false?

"Every ring R with infinite elements has $\mathrm{char}(R)=0$"

My answer was that $\Bbb Z_2 [x] $ is a ring with infinite elements such that for a polynomial $f(x) $ in $\Bbb Z_2 [x] $, the sum of $f(x)+f(x)=0$, in particular, for the unit element, $1+1=0$, so $\mathrm{char}(\Bbb Z_2 [x]) =2$ and the statement is False.

Is this correct?

Comment: That question and solution are easily found on the site, namely [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/356649/29335) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1192733/29335). You really ought to search and find those before asking.

Comment: Dear @bof : What is the difference, in your mind, between proof-verification and seeing ones own answer confirmed in several other places as proof?  (Don't worry, I plan to ignore the condescension of your comment as well-intended.). Regards

Comment: @bof If the thing being verified wasn't present  in other solutions, I would not be speaking so, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.$ $$ $$ $$ $

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/867302)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos "Yes" is definitely an answer to "is this correct".